# Access a variable outside of a promise

Tags: node.js, promise

I am writing a steam bot and am trying to check, if one of the items in a trade is worth below 1 USD. I need to access the "pass" variable, but it never works. Can someone help?

```
    var receive = offer.itemsToReceive;
    var pass = true;
    receive.forEach(function(id) {
      var args = id.split(",");
      market.getItemPrice("some app id", some item name).then(function(result) {
        var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)); // returns e.G $0.08
        var price = parseFloat(json.median_price.substring(1));

        if(price*100 < 100) {
           pass = false;
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: If you want access to the pass variable after it has been changed, you will have to write a function that returns pass as a promise.

assuming getItemPrice returns a promise.
    var pass = true;
    getItemPrice("some app id").then(function(result) {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pass = false;
            return resolve(pass)
          });
     }).then(pass => console.log(pass)); //call a different function with pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is asked a lot, but hopefully explaining it in your own problem's terms will help you understand.

Your code should wait for any possibility of `pass = false;`, but it doesn't because you call a asynchronous function --- imagine the code immediately moves on after calling that. Your foreach function is immediately processed and the next line is called until `.getItemPrice` responds some time later.

So instead, to "wait" for all the results, you can do something like:

```
var receive = offer.itemsToReceive;
var pass = true;
var itemReceivePromises = receive.map(id=>{
  var args = id.split(",");
  return market.getItemPrice("some app id", some item name).then(function(result) {
    var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)); // returns e.G $0.08
    var price = parseFloat(json.median_price.substring(1));

    if(price*100 < 100) {
       pass = false;
    }
  });
});
Promise.all(itemRecievePromises).then(results=>{
  console.log('pass',pass);
});
```

However, you should pass the "pass" result back through the promise instead of using a higher scoped variable.